# HP iLo Firmware Upgrade For HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9 Running freeBSD

Tags: freebsd, hp-proliant

OS: FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p4

I am in a bit of a situation. I need to upgrade iLo on a an HP 360DL box but all the hponcfg utilities I need are only linux(debian or redhat) packages.

Here are some links to documentation.

[HP Utilities needed for upgrade.](https://blog.tinned-software.net/install-hp-proliant-management-utilities/)

[HP support page that doesn't work because i am running freeBSD 11](https://people.freebsd.org/~jcagle/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. I extracted the bin file from the HP firmware package by doing

```
CP032487.scexe --unpack=/<unpack path>
```

I installed apache on the server, and mapped the ilo4_255.bin file on the server with an apache alias.

```
Alias /ilo4_255.bin /foo/foobar/ilo4_255.bin
<Directory /foo/foobar/ilo4_255.bin>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then I ssh'd into the iLo box itself and ran

```
load /map1/firmware1 -source http://<host>/ilo4_255.bin
```

And just like that we are all fixed up!

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade iLO through its own web UI, through *Administration* → *Firmware*. For example, if it's iLO 4, then upload the `ILO4_270.BIN` file (which can be [extracted](https://pingtool.org/latest-hp-ilo-firmwares/) from the official .scexe or Windows .exe package using 7zip).

[image: Screenshot of iLO4 web interface showing the "Firmware Update" page]

Comment: The web console is not available in our environment. Any other options?